# How to move labels (from map exports) using program like photoshop?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, gimp

In the past, I have exported from QGIS composer some maps in `.pdf` and some in `.png`.

In those exports I release to have some wrong (placed) labels and I have I release to lose the QGIS projects where I use for exports and is very hard to start again with to take some results.

Can I use some program like `Photoshop`,`illustrator`,`GIMP`,`adode pdf pro`,`Adobe Creative Suite`,`adobe illustrator cs6` to move that wrong labels to other place in map?

Comment: export to svg > you still need to separate the layers for text and un-group them then you can move individual elements.

Comment: see https://anitagraser.com/2011/09/01/editing-labels-in-qgis-svg-output-using-inkscape/

Comment: it seems like the project file is lost? So no export to svg...

Answer (score 1):

Use OGR2OGR to convert your GeospatialPDF/GeoPDF to Shapefile.  Then move the labels with QGIS.  OGR2OGR -f "ESRI Shapefile" outputpath/filename.shp sourcepdf.pdf  Alternatively, you can import the geopdf into Global Mapper 18x as Vector Layer and move the labels then Export Raster.

Answer (score 1):

Export to SVG and you can use Inkscape to edit the labels (open source vector graphic editor like illustrator)

An alternative is to place the file into photoshop with no existing labels and place them manually. - not the best case when you have a lot of labels.